# Must be called after notifyItemInserted

Tags: android

Must [notifyItemRangeChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object)) be called after calling [notifyItemInserted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int)) in an RecyclerView.Adapter?
There are so many examples on SO where they always call notifyItemRangeChanged after notifyItemInserted but I am not sure this is really correct? If this is correct what would be the explanation? What would the case be where you don't need to call notifyItemRangeChanged, otherwise it would be part of notifyItemInserted?

Answer (score 0):

There are no rules as one method should always precede the other.

If there is an addition of a new item, then call `notifyItemInserted`. If items are changed, then call `notifyItemRangeChanged`.

If some items are added and some are changed, you have to call both methods with respective positions as arguments. You can call the methods in any order, but based on the order the animations and the position that you have to pass to the methods might change.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation for RecyclerView:

> There are two different classes of data change events, **item changes** and **structural changes**. **Item changes** are when a single item has its data updated but **no positional changes** have occurred. **Structural changes** are **when items are inserted, removed or moved** within the data set.

`notifyItemInserted`

Is a structural change event

`notifyItemRangeChanged`

Is a item change event

> What would the case be where you don't need to call
>   notifyItemRangeChanged, otherwise it would be part of
>   notifyItemInserted?

Well its not necessary to always call `notifyItemRangeChanged` when `notifyItemInserted` since they both serve different purposes.

To put it in a simple way, if you add a new row/data to existing adapter's dataset then you should call `notifyItemInserted`.

If you modify certain data in bulk in the adapter's dataset, without adding, moving or deleting the adapter's dataset's content then call `notifyItemRangeChanged`. For single item change use `notifyItemChanged`